# How to disable tab button for specific inputs in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs

I have inputs on a few pages which I animate through. You have to click the button to get the next page and the next round of inputs, however when you get to the end of each page, you can hit the tab button and it focuses on the next input field which throws off the animation flow and display. Can I disable the tab button?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your goal is to disable "tabbing out" of an input field, you can listen to the `keyDown` event, and if the `keyCode` is `9` (value for Tab), then `preventDefault` on the event:

```
function MyComponent() {
  return <input onKeyDown={(e) => { if (e.keyCode === 9) e.preventDefault() }} />
}
```

Rest of your code stays the same; i.e. however you handle input change:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <input
      value={value}
      onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      onKeyDown={(e) => {
        if (e.keyCode === 9) e.preventDefault();
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

---

From an accessibility and user experience perspective, I'd suggest not disabling `Tab` functionality. Some of your users might not have a mouse/touch input device or capability, or might want or prefer to use the keyboard exclusively for navigation. `Tab` is the natural way to advance among inputs, links, and buttons on web pages and it's best if you can preserve the functionality. Is there a way to deliver your animation experience while preserving `Tab` navigation?

Answer (score 8):

If all you want to do is prevent the field from receiving focus from a tab, you can set the `tabIndex` attribute to `-1`.

```html
<form>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
  <button>button</button>
  <input type="text" tabIndex="-1" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a sandbox to show you how to do this using React refs. Essentially, you can use the ref to store the DOM element you want to modify, making it really reusuable. In this case we just want to set that input's tabIndex to -1

https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-fermat-vihnc

```
function App() {
  const skipInputRef = React.createRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    skipInputRef.current.tabIndex = -1;
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input />
      <input />
      <input ref={skipInputRef} placeholder="skip" />
      <button>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is great, love the use of refs.. they always save the day.